# Bugs while debugging firefox addon- Unchecked lastError value: Error

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm using Firefox browser's JavaScript Debugger to debug my addon. I'm getting dozens and dozens of repeated 
Unchecked lastError value: Error: ID already exists: append
Unchecked lastError value: Error: ID already exists: convert

[image: errors]
It doesn't get in the way of the addon functioning, but why am I getting these errors from ExtensionCommon.jsm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. It means an extension is sending a message that doesn't have a corresponding listener, and not handling the error correctly.

Try to console log so as to know exactly what is been generated on each error occurrence.

Hope it helps.